# Adding zeros in a digital clock

Tags: javascript

I have researched for an hour now on how to do add the zeros whenever hours, minutes or seconds are less 10, to make them, for example, "05 hours", and not just "5 hours".

I have tried `if (hours < 10) { hours = "0" + hours }` and I've seen it work in a couple of websites, but it doesn't seem to work in my code.

How can I make this work?

```js
function clock() {
    //Clock variables
    var today = new Date();
    var hours = today.getHours();
    var minutes = today.getMinutes();
    var seconds = today.getSeconds();
    var date1 = [hours, minutes, seconds];
    var actualDate = date1.join(":");

    //Adding zeros, but it doesn't work.
    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    //text
    document.getElementById("hey").innerHTML = actualDate;


    //Repeat every 1000ms (1 second)
    setTimeout(clock, 1000);
};
clock();
```

```html
<h1 id="hey"></h1>
```

Comment: What do you mean writing "it doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: Maybe `join` after you changed that??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you need to calculate `date1` and `actualdate` after prepending zeroes on the values.

```js
function clock() {
  //Clock variables
  var today = new Date();
  var hours = today.getHours();
  var minutes = today.getMinutes();
  var seconds = today.getSeconds();
  

  //Adding zeros, but it doesn't work.
  if (hours < 10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }

  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }
  
  var date1 = [hours, minutes, seconds];
  var actualDate = date1.join(":");
  
  //text
  document.getElementById("hey").innerHTML = actualDate;


  //Repeat every 1000ms (1 second)
  setTimeout(clock, 1000);
};
clock();
```

```html
<h1 id="hey"></h1>
```

I would suggest you to use **`padStart`** of ES8 to do this task.

```js
var x = "5";
console.log(x.padStart(2, "0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use this `pad` function :

```
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```

in node :

```
> function pad(num, size) {
...     var s = num+"";
...     while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
...     return s;
... }
> pad(1, 2)
'01'
> pad(11, 2)
'11'
>
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (seconds < 10) { seconds = "0" + seconds; }` this will just add the `number` 0 to the `number` of seconds. So you have to make your numbers a string:

```js
function clock() {
    //Clock variables
    var today = new Date();
    var hours = today.getHours().toString();
    var minutes = today.getMinutes().toString();
    var seconds = today.getSeconds().toString();


    //Adding zeros, but it doesn't work.
    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    var date1 = [hours, minutes, seconds];
    var actualDate = date1.join(":");

    //text
    document.getElementById("hey").innerHTML = actualDate;


    //Repeat every 1000ms (1 second)
    setTimeout(clock, 1000);
};
clock();
```

```html
<h1 id="hey"></h1>
```